# Как распарсить диалог?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Есть html  файл с диалогом двух пользователей. Как можно распарсить его, что бы на выходе получился json содержащий вопрос абонента А, ответ абонента Б. Примерно так

```
 {
     "абонент а сказал": ["привет"],
     "абонент б ответил": ["пока"]
    }
```

Пример html разметки

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Exported Data</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>

  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript">

  </script>

 </head>

 <body onload="CheckLocation();">

  <div class="page_wrap">

   <div class="page_header">

    <div class="content">

     <div class="text bold">
Deleted Account
     </div>

    </div>

   </div>

   <div class="page_body chat_page">

    <div class="history">

     <div class="message service" id="message-1">

      <div class="body details">
16 May 2018
      </div>

     </div>

     <div class="message default clearfix" id="message21365">

      <div class="pull_left userpic_wrap">

       <div class="userpic userpic2" style="width: 42px; height: 42px">

        <div class="initials" style="line-height: 42px">
абонент а
        </div>

       </div>

      </div>

      <div class="body">

       <div class="pull_right date details" title="16.05.2018 20:21:39">
20:21
       </div>

       <div class="from_name">
абонент а 
       </div>

       <div class="text">
ты?
       </div>

      </div>

     </div>

     <div class="message default clearfix" id="message21366">

      <div class="pull_left userpic_wrap">

       <div class="userpic userpic7" style="width: 42px; height: 42px">

        <div class="initials" style="line-height: 42px">

        </div>

       </div>

      </div>

      <div class="body">

       <div class="pull_right date details" title="16.05.2018 20:21:54">
20:21
       </div>

       <div class="from_name">
Deleted Account
       </div>

       <div class="text">
Я
       </div>

      </div>

     </div>

     <div class="message default clearfix joined" id="message21367">

      <div class="body">

       <div class="pull_right date details" title="16.05.2018 20:22:01">
20:22
       </div>

       <div class="text">
а может ты?
       </div>

      </div>

     </div>

     <div class="message default clearfix joined" id="message21368">

      <div class="body">

       <div class="pull_right date details" title="16.05.2018 20:22:02">
20:22
       </div>

       <div class="text">
а?
       </div>

      </div>

     </div>

     <div class="message default clearfix" id="message21369">

      <div class="pull_left userpic_wrap">

       <div class="userpic userpic2" style="width: 42px; height: 42px">

        <div class="initials" style="line-height: 42px">
абонент а
        </div>

       </div>

      </div>

      <div class="body">

       <div class="pull_right date details" title="16.05.2018 20:22:24">
20:22
       </div>

       <div class="from_name">
абонент а 
       </div>

       <div class="text">
не
       </div>

      </div>

     </div>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что здесь нет такого формата `имя1: сообщение имя2: сообщение`. Тут после `имя1` может быть 10  сообщений. Я сначала пробовал получить два масивал, один с именами другой с сообщениями а потом просто объединить их, но исходя из описаной выше проблемы, сообщений получается больше чем имен. Как быть в таком случае?
пример результата на основе html

```
 {
     "абонент а сказал": ["ты?"],
     "абонент б ответил": ["я а может ты? а?"]
    },{
     "абонент а сказал": ["не"],
     "абонент б ответил": ["тут сл. сообщение"]
    }
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, желаемый результат на основе Вашего `HTML`.

Comment: в суп и по селекторам)

Comment: обновил содержимое вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`Json`", который Вы привели, как пример ожидаемого результата, не валиден, поэтому я не стал его придерживаться и просто спарсил необходимые Вам данные, оставив задачу их форматирования и отображения на Вас.

К тому же, в `HTML` нет никакого намёка на строку `абонент б`.
Видимо, Вы имели в виду строки из `<div class="from_name">...</div>`, поэтому я и брал их.

***Пример:***

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


def parse(html: str) -> list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    res = []
    messages = soup.find_all('div', re.compile(r'message default'))
    for message in messages:
        tmp_from_name = message.find('div', {'class': 'from_name'})

        if tmp_from_name is not None:
            from_name = tmp_from_name.getText().strip()

        text = message.find('div', {'class': 'text'}).getText().strip()
        res.append({from_name: text})
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('index.html', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        html = f.read()

    res = parse(html)
    print(res)
```

***stdout:***

```py
[{'абонент а': 'ты?'}, {'Deleted Account': 'Я'}, {'Deleted Account': 'а может ты?'}, {'Deleted Account': 'а?'}, {'абонент а': 'не'}]
```

Comment: Спасибо все круто, но я бы внес маленькую поправку. При запуске кода в таком виде вылетает ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText' . Я добавил проверку if text is not None: и теперь все идеально. Спасибо!